# How to produce a matrix with two values per colums in R

Tags: r, matrix, combinations, multiple-columns

I have two matrices

```
means16 <- matrix(nrow = 4, ncol = 6)
median16 <- matrix(nrow = 4, ncol = 6)
```

which contain means and median values for prices of different products. I would like to combine them like this:

```
               range1        range2        range3         range4         range5          range6
            mean  median  mean  median  mean  median   mean  median   mean  median    mean  median
Product1    
Product2
Product3
Product4
```

How can one insert a second level for each column to provide space for mean and median values?

Cheers,

Comment: For some reasons "Hello" is not displayed, even after editing.. so, Hello and thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just to display them together, you can directly use paste0:

```
means16 <- matrix(data = sample(1:10,6*4,replace = T),nrow = 4, ncol = 6)
median16 <- matrix(data = sample(1:10,6*4,replace = T),nrow = 4, ncol = 6)
matrix(paste0(means16," - ",median16), nrow = 4, ncol = 6)
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    [,4]     [,5]     [,6]    
[1,] "5 - 3"  "5 - 1"  "2 - 4" "8 - 9"  "10 - 9" "2 - 6" 
[2,] "10 - 3" "1 - 2"  "3 - 6" "5 - 3"  "2 - 6"  "7 - 6" 
[3,] "9 - 9"  "5 - 10" "9 - 6" "10 - 4" "7 - 5"  "7 - 8" 
[4,] "3 - 9"  "7 - 9"  "2 - 4" "6 - 2"  "7 - 1"  "10 - 3"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasons not to do this, but you can assign a matrix to a column in a data frame:

```
means16 <- matrix(data = sample(1:10, 6*4, replace = T),
     nrow = 4, ncol = 6)
medians16 <- matrix(data = sample(1:10, 6*4, replace = T),
     nrow = 4, ncol = 6)
```

We need a list with 6 2-column matrices (one for each range):

```
pairs <- lapply(1:6, function(x) cbind(means16[, x],
     medians16[, x]))
names(pairs) <- paste0("range", 1:6)
for (i in 1:6) colnames(pairs[[i]]) <- c("mean", "median")
```

Now we put those 2-column matrices into a data frame:

```
new <- data.frame(matrix(NA, 4, 6))
names(new) <- paste0("range", 1:6)
for (i in 1:6) new[, i] <- pairs[[i]]
str(new)
```

You will see that columns range1 to range6 each consist of a 2-column matrix with column names "mean" and "median". This data structure will be difficult to work with. Without knowing how you plan to use it, it is not clear if it is worth the effort.

Comment: Why is this way of presentation not recommended? Next step is to calculate the differences of the means and medians between two years.

Comment: It is complicated to specify individual columns within each matrix which will make it easier to make mistakes. Naming separate columns new$range1.mn and new$range1.md is simpler than specifying new$range1[, "mean"] and new$range1[, "median"].